# Can a statement be both negative and positive after saying "Whatever you do..."?

Tags: sentence

Sometimes you are given advice. Sometimes in the form of

> What ever you do, *statement*

Can this statement be both positive and negative? E.g.

> Whatever you do, don't take off your seat belt while driving.
>
> Whatever you do, keep your seat belt on while driving.
>
> Whatever you do, don't ignore your customers.
>
> Whatever you do, always listen to your customers.

The positive statements seem odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I have a feeling it may be because you are using the language to be **restrictive**.

For example:

> Whatever you do, don't take off your seat belt while driving.

You are essentially saying this:

> You may do anything you wish to while driving, except take off your seat belt. Taking off your seatbelt is the one thing you must not do.

The positive, however, is less forceful:

> Whatever you do, keep your seat belt on while driving.

Which, translated, means:

> You may do anything you wish to while driving, but also keep your seat belt on. Keeping your seat belt on is one of the many things you may/should/must do while driving.

"*Whatever you do*" is a fairly strong (to my ear) phrasing, so perhaps it is not surprising that it is generally used by people giving strong advice. I hope that makes some sort of sense.

Having said that, I don't think the positives are *wrong* at all. They just aren't used as commonly, methinks, and for the reasons above. That's why they sound a little strange to you.